# C - How to split a string with delimiter when sometimes there are no values between delimiter?

Tags: c, split, segmentation-fault, c-strings, strtok

I am trying to split a string as follows:
`1.97E+13,1965.10.30,12:47:01 AM,39.1,23,greece,,,,,10,4.8,4.6,4.6,4.8,4.6,4.7`

I am using `strtok` and giving `,` as a delimiter but since there are no values between some commas I get a segmentation fault.

What is the correct way to assign null values to consecutive commas?

Comment: You can use `strchr` to find the commas. Things get more difficult if there are quoted strings in the data and those strings contain commas, e.g. `1,2,3,"hello, world",4,5`

Comment: The lack of characters between delimiters does not make `strtok` fail. Something else in your code is causing that. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `strtok` use functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "1.97E+13, 1965.10.30, 12:47 : 01 AM, 39.1, 23, "
        "greece, , , , , 10, 4.8, 4.6, 4.6, 4.8, 4.6, 4.7";

    const char *delin = ",";

    for (const char *p = s; *p; p += *p != '\0')
    {
        size_t n = strcspn( p, delin );
        if (n == 0)
        {
            puts( "empty" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\"%.*s\"\n", ( int )n, p );
        }

        p += n;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
"1.97E+13"
" 1965.10.30"
" 12:47 : 01 AM"
" 39.1"
" 23"
" greece"
" "
" "
" "
" "
" 10"
" 4.8"
" 4.6"
" 4.6"
" 4.8"
" 4.6"
" 4.7"
```

Comment: As a plus -- you can use `strspn` and `strcspn` with string-literals without modifying the original `:)`